# Adding link against each row in grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to display a 'Delete' link against each row in a editorgridpanel.
How do I create this link;as it is not mapped to any particular column in the store?
I tried the following but it does not display the link against the added records:

```
 var sampleRecord = new Ext.data.Record.create([
        {mapping: 'organizationId',name:'organizationId', type:'int'},
        {mapping: 'name',name:'name', type:'string'},
        {mapping: 'address',name:'address' , type:'int'}
        ]);

    var s_grid= new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel ({
        .........
            columns: [
                  {header: 'id', width: 120, sortable: false, dataIndex: 'organizationId'},
                  {header: 'name',width: 120, sortable: false, dataIndex: 'name'},
                  {header: 'address', sortable: false,width: 45, dataIndex: 'address'},
                  {header: '',width: 50, sortable: false, renderer:this.delRenderer }
             ],
            .....
,
            delRenderer:function (val, meta, rec, rowIdx) {
                var tempStr="<div onclick=\"javascript:Ext.getCmp('" +"s_grid" + "').deAllocate(" + rowIdx + ");\" class='pointer'><span style='color:#0000FF'><u>Delete</u></span></div>";
                return tempStr ;
            },
            deAllocate:function (rowIdx ) {
                Ext.getCmp('s_grid').getStore().removeAt(rowIdx);
                Ext.getCmp('s_grid').getView().refresh();
            }

            });
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using an [`ActionColumn`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.ActionColumn). Anyway, you can also wrap a solution around custom element (link...) with the [`cellclick`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-cellclick) event. Here's an [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3ei) showing both methods:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,height: 300

    ,store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['id', 'name']
        ,data: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Foo'}
            ,{id: 2, name: 'Bar'}
            ,{id: 3, name: 'Baz'}
        ]
    })

    ,columns: [
        {dataIndex: 'name'}
        ,{
            xtype: 'actioncolumn'
            ,icon: 'http://images.agoramedia.com/everydayhealth/gcms/icon_delete_16px.gif'
            ,handler: function(grid, row) {
                grid.store.removeAt(row);
            }
        }
        ,{
            renderer: function(value, md, record, row, col, store) {
                return '<a class="delete-link" href="#delete-record-' + record.id + '">Delete</a>';
            }
        }
    ]

    ,listeners: {
        cellclick: function(grid, row, col, e) {
            var el = e.getTarget('a.delete-link');
            if (el) {
                e.preventDefault();
                grid.store.removeAt(row);
            }
        }
    }
});

var lastId = 3;    
setInterval(function() {
    var store = grid.store,
        record = new store.recordType({id: ++lastId, name: 'New record #' + lastId}, lastId);
    store.add(record);
}, 3000);
```

**Update**

And just because I may be completely off topic on your question, I think your code is not working because when you call this:

```
renderer: this.delRenderer
```

Your not in a scope where `this` points to your grid (since it has not even been created at this point...). What you want to do is rather something like this:

```
var s_grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel ({
    ...
    columns: [..., {
        ...
        renderer: delRenderer
    }]
});

function delRenderer() {
    // FYI, `this` will be the column here
    ...
}
```

Or put the function inline in the grid definition...

Comment: And, as pointed by matt, the `dataindex` option is theoretically required. So you may want to set it to anything in your action columns, even though it visibly works without it in my fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

You can change model by adding delete field :

```
    {
      name: 'delete',
      convert: function () {
        return '<a href="#">delete</a>';
    }
```

> You can then add extra column in your grid and check for link click by 'cellclick' event of the grid with some modifications.Here is the working example :
>   [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/9GLr7/11/).

Have a nice day :-)

Comment: Consider he is using ExtJS 3.

Comment: oops didn't look at that!!:)

Answer (score 0):

The [`dataIndex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-dataIndex) config is required on your column, so just provide any field there (e.g. the id) and in your renderer function just ignore the `value` argument (as you are already doing).